# How to get all active sessions from SessionBag in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

On website I'm working on I need to be able to modify variables within active sessions depending on some server event. I have identified that there is the list of sessions in SessionBag variable (within Service) so I am wondering how I can search this collection to get certain users session and modify it if needed?